# How to import Java static method into Drools file?

Tags: java, drools, static-methods

The `java` class and static method code is:

```
public class DroolsStringUtils {
    public static boolean isEmpty(String param) {
        if (param == null || "".equals(param)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `drl` code is:

```
package com.rules

import com.secbro.drools.utils.DroolsStringUtils.isEmpty;

rule CheckIsEmpty
  when
    isEmpty("");
  then
    System.out.println("the param is not empty");
  end
```

But the IDEA hints:

`"cannot relove" on the method 'isEmpty("")'`.

I just want to import a static method from `java` class to `drl` file.

Comment: the drools version is 7.0.0.Final

Comment: the IDEA is intellij IDEA 2016.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use import *static* to import a static method.

```
import  static  com.secbro.drools.utils.DroolsStringUtils.isEmpty;
//      ^^^^^^
```

(edited:) and of course you cannot call a static method where a pattern is required:

```
rule CheckIsEmpty
when
    eval( isEmpty("") )
then
    System.out.println("the param is not empty");
end
```

(It helps considerably to read the Drools documentation.)

Comment: Thanks! I has tried,but got the same result. And the Drools document' example is 'import function my.package.Foo.hello'.  But in my code ,it does work either.

Comment: Thre exception is 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, kieBase=rules, level=ERROR, path=Rules.drl, line=8, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'isEmpty']]

Comment: Saw your "rule"; you can't write a condition this way.

Comment: Thanks very much! As you say, I got the Answer. At the same time ,I find that the intellij idea gave the wrong warning. The code can work,but the IDEA always show 'Connot resovle '  warning. And The keyword 'static' is same to 'function'.

Comment: I might have missed the announcement but I've never heard of IDEA support for Drools.

Comment: @laune how do you do the same but without using `eval` from drools. Consider the function has other function dependencies and its too large to write a drools function. I am having this issue since `eval` is deprecated.

Comment: IDEA support for Drools (at least by now): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16871-drools

Answer (score 2):

[this might have details only relevant for Drools 6.0 & earlier (thanks [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072844/how-to-import-java-static-method-into-drools-file/45073795#comment122355587_66190074))]

[Looks like](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html#d0e5676) you could import the static method, as a `function` into Drools...

```
import function com.secbro.drools.utils.DroolsStringUtils.isEmpty
```

...and then be able to use your rule as you wrote it originally in your Question.

- It seems [classic Java-style] [static imports are not supported in
  Drools](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html#d0e5619)
- But it seems they can be imported with [Drools function import
  style](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html#d0e5676)

FWIW: To reference static fields - import the class with the static fields as normal import (not `static` or `function`), and then refer to `static` field with static reference:

```
import your.package.with.static.field.YourClass

...

YourClass.STATIC_FIELD
```

(That also works for static methods too, if you don't want to import them as `function`).

Comment: Static imports work for me, not sure why the documentation seems to indicate otherwise -- but I note you've linked to a really old version (6.0).

Comment: This solution worked for me when calling a static method in the when section. I found that I needed to wrap the call to the static method in an eval like so:
eval( YourClass.staticMethod() );