# How to import a function from a Java classes static method drools 6.5

Tags: java, function, import, drools

I'm having trouble getting the function importing to work from Java class to drools DRL.  For example with the following DRL:

```
package rules

import com.company.my.Person;

import function com.company.my.FunctionUtility.allowVote;

dialect  "java"

ruleflow-group "PersonRules"

rule "person can vote"
    when
        $p:Person(age > 17)
    then
        allowVote();
end
```

referencing imported Java Function:

```
public class FunctionUtility {
  public static void allowVote(){
      System.out.println("Voting allowed");
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when doing mvn clean install:

```
The method allowVote() is undefined for the type Rule_Person_Can_Vote
Only a type can be imported.  com.company.my.FunctionUtility.allowVote resolves to a package
```

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072844/drools-imports-java-static-method) had a similar ask, but their solution is not consistent with the [drools documentatio](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e8178)n or this [6.5.0 unit test](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/0238cb8f6d4d5236beed79202a11e4d2ef3f20dc/drools-compiler/src/test/resources/org/drools/compiler/integrationtests/drl/test_ImportFunctions.drl#L19) for importing functions and doesn't work for me in any case.

Has anyone gotten function imports to work with drools 6.x, and if so how did you do it?

Comment: import static gives me the same error

Comment: Why do you need this tested method to be `static`?

Comment: I don't need the method to be static, but the documentation says "you could use a static method in a helper class, e.g., Foo.hello()".  I tried also without static and got the same error.

Comment: Have you tried a full path like com.company.my.FunctionUtility.allowVote();?

Comment: Yes that gives me a different error, FunctionUtility cannot be resolved to a type.  I tried importing just FunctionUtility too, but that gave me the original error.

Comment: *"I don't need the method to be static"* then do not make it `static`. As a rule of thumb do not declare anything `static` *unless you have a good reason* to do so. A random API documentation telling you you *can* do it **is not** a good reason.

Comment: Timothy as I said I've tried both static and non-static and neither are working.  It's not a random API documentation, it's the documentation for drools which I'm working with.  If you don't have anything positive to add please don't comment.

Comment: The wording of the error message "...allowVote() is undefined for the type Rule_Person_Can_Vote" suggests to me that this is diagnosed by a Java compiler when compiling the Java code generated from the DRL. I suggest that you check that your classpath for the compiler call contains a .class file FunctionUtility when compiling the generated Java code. (I never use maven so I can't suggest where to look. But the import of a static method does work as documented.)